# Eliminate render-blocking JS - mobile menu causing low page speed score

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagespeed

I have a low scoring site on Google PageSpeed for mobile only (approx 55/100) which is down to:

"Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content"

It's the mobile menu causing the issue (when it's removed score jumps to 90)

Code for menu:

```
<div id="mobile-header">
     <a id="MenuToggle" class="menu-button" href="javascript:void(0)">&nbsp;</a>
</div>
```

which calls on the following two scripts that are **in the footer just before closing body**.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/min/custom-min.js"></script>
```

custom-min.js contains:

```
    $('#MenuToggle').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('cross'),
    $('#jqmenu').slideToggle('slow', function () {
    });

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollDown: 0
    }, 1000);
});
```

Can I defer this at all to keep Page Speed happy?

Many thanks.

EDIT: This is only happening on the homepage, which baffles me as all pages have the same header and footer setup.

Comment: Why don't you do some tests on your side?

Comment: I have been for the past 2 hours. I'm stumped. Googling has just returned that usually the issue is when the files are loaded into the head rather than just above the body.

Comment: *Above the fold* in general applies to the portion of the page that is visible on page load that does not require scrolling in order to see the content. You can either load your files asynchronously or put your styles inline for that portion of the page. In your case you may have to do both.